# Cannot install aws-cli from edge repository on Alpine linux

Tags: linux, docker, alpine-linux

I'm trying to install aws-cli from edge repository but I cannot

https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/community/x86_64/aws-cli

Is it an issue with OS version? ( 3.11 / 3.12 )

If so is there a workaround?

```
root@6f97c6559fe9:/ # echo http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main >> /etc/apk/repositories 
root@6f97c6559fe9:/ # apk update
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.11/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.11/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
v3.11.6-71-gb45d3b45cc [http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.11/main]
v3.11.6-68-gf6abc2afac [http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.11/community]
v3.12.0-442-g76e377ea0b [http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main]
OK: 16123 distinct packages available

root@6f97c6559fe9:/ # apk add aws-cli
ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
  aws-cli (missing):
    required by: world[aws-cli]
root@6f97c6559fe9:/ # apk add --update aws-cli
ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
  aws-cli (missing):
    required by: world[aws-cli]

root@6f97c6559fe9:/ # cat /etc/os-release 
NAME="Alpine Linux"
ID=alpine
VERSION_ID=3.11.3
PRETTY_NAME="Alpine Linux v3.11"
HOME_URL="https://alpinelinux.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.alpinelinux.org/"
```

Comment: Seems like. I can reproduce, at least, 3.12 install properly when 3.11 does not

Comment: And the package page seems to confirm: https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=aws-cli&branch=v3.11

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60298619/awscli-version-2-on-alpine-linux

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the [package page](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=aws-cli&branch=v3.11) of Alpine seems to confirm that `aws-cli` is indeed not part of Alpine 3.11 package repository.

This said, you can install it using [AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-linux.html#install-linux-bundled) own set of instructions, you will just need both `curl` and `python` in order to do so.

For AWS CLI v1:

```sh
apk add python curl
curl "https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-cli/awscli-bundle.zip" -o "awscli-bundle.zip"
unzip awscli-bundle.zip
./awscli-bundle/install -i /usr/local/aws -b /usr/local/bin/aws
```

<sup>*Source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-linux.html#install-linux-bundled*</sup>

For AWS CLI v2, sadly, it seems Alpine is not yet supported:

> [**nateprewitt** *commented on 24 Feb*](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/4971#issuecomment-590538014)
>   Hi @firstval, it looks like you found
>   a response on this behavior in [#4685](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/4685). We're currently tracking Docker
>   support in [#3553](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/3553) which would be a prerequisite for this to work.
>
> That said, we can definitely do better with the exceptions being
>   returned. We're working on getting a warning in our install script to
>   will alert you when the platform isn't supported.
>
> We'll track the remaining piece for alpine support in [#3553](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/3553). Thanks!

<sup>*Source: https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/4971*</sup>

Further down in [#3553](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/3553):

- There is an official docker image for aws-cli: https://hub.docker.com/r/amazon/aws-cli
- Some people got it working, but with quite a huge amount of dependancies needed (you actually need a c compiler, as it seems): https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/3553#issuecomment-615149941

This would also explain why, even on Alpine 3.12, the actual package install the version [1.xx](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/community/x86_64/aws-cli) and not a 2.xx version.

Comment: This method installs aws in version **aws-cli/1.18.74 Python/2.7.18 Linux/4.9.0-9-amd64 botocore/1.16.24** but locally I have version **aws-cli/2.0.5 Python/3.7.3 Linux/4.9.0-9-amd64 botocore/2.0.0dev9** is there a way to install latest version?

Comment: Yes, there is also in the same AWS help sections, I did copy here the v1 client because on the Alpine package, it also install the version 1.xx. Let me throw a little update to the answer

Comment: I've allowed myself to edit your post with output of my attempt of installing v2. Unfortunately it didn't work for me. Feel free to remove it.

Comment: Not an answer to your question: https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/4971