# Error creating JSON string in github action

Tags: json, jq, github-actions

In one of my steps in a github action, I am trying to create a JSON string that I can use in a later step.

I get an error on the following step,

```
- name: Generate JSON string
        run: echo "JSON_STRING=$( jq -n \
                --arg image "foo" \
                --arg region "us-west-2" \
                --arg secret "mysecret" \
                --arg env "prod" \
                '{"flask":{"image": $image,"ports":{"5000":"HTTP"},"environment":{"FLASK_ENV":$env,"AWS_SECRET_NAME": $secret,"AWS_REGION_NAME": $region}}}' )" >> $GITHUB_ENV
```

In a terminal shell (ubuntu), I am able to run this command and generate a JSON string.

Comment: Which error do you get?

Comment: It looks like a syntax error; "You have an error in your yaml syntax on line 41" .  I am not too sure of the syntax for JSON in Yaml files.

Comment: Things I would try for testing: Eliminate the backslashes by putting all into one line and see if the error has gone. If not, also eliminate the call to `jq` by assigning the JSON object directly:  `JSON_STRING='{"flask":{"image":"foo","ports":{"5000":"HTTP"},"environment":{"FLASK_ENV":"prod","AWS_SECRET_NAME":"mysecret","AWS_REGION_NAME":"us-west-2"}}}'`

Comment: My suggestion is that your command substitution `$(...)` is not expanding as in the terminal.

Comment: I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65159967/gitlab-ci-cd-to-amazon-lightsail; so far this work run: echo `"{\"flask\":{\"image\":\"$PIPELINE_IMAGE_TAG\",\"ports\":{\"5000\":\"HTTP\"},\"environment\":{\"FLASK_ENV\":\"${{ secrets.FLASK_ENV }}\",\"AWS_SECRET_NAME\":\"${{ secrets.AWS_SECRETS_NAME }}\",\"AWS_REGION_NAME\":\"${{ secrets.AWS_REGION }}\"}}}"`

Answer (score 0):

Your step appends `JSON_STRING=value` to `$GITHUB_ENV`. This causes the `JSON_STRING` environment variable to be set in subsequent steps.

Normally `GITHUB_ENV` contains one `VAR=value` per line. Though, multiline values can also be added [if they're surrounded by delimiters](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#multiline-strings).

So the problem is that `jq` formats its output on multiple lines by default. A simple fix would be to pass `--compact-output / -c` to `jq` so that your JSON string fits on a single line.